# Boost PFC compensator saturation issue

Tags: operational-amplifier, control, power-factor-correction

I try to use a simulation tool to model the PFC circuit.
There is a weird thing I can't very understand.
Please see the below figure from my simulation.
As you can see the output is 400V, after the divided by two resistors and compensating it, the output of OPA is saturation, and I do not have any idea how to solve this issue.
Can this issue be solved?

I know the saturation reason because the output voltage is not constant at 400V, the output value will large than 400V and small than 400V, if the output is above 400V, the output of OPA will be 10V, if the output is below 400V, the output of OPA will be 0V.

[image]

system block diagram

[image]

Comment: Sounds like your converter is unstable, how did you choose the compensation components?  Without a full schematic of the converter, control scheme and more information it's hard to say what's going on for sure.

Comment: @JohnD, 

I update the context, the schematic looks like this.
My circuit can be stable if I add the limit to my circuit.

Comment: For the PFC, the outer voltage loop bandwidth has to be very low so as not to introduce distortion into the current.  Maybe around10 Hz.  That's one thing to consider.  There are many PFC circuits with this topology that work fine, so it's certainly possible to make it work.

Comment: @JohnD the voltage loop crossover frequency is 10Hz, I try to use OTA to be a compensator circuit the circuit could work, but if I replace the OTA to OPA, the circuit can't work. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What's the GBW and closed-loop BW of the op-amp compensator vs. the gm amplifier?  Could the op-amp have lower bandwidth and therefore be adding enough phase shift to make the loop unstable?  How about the supply rails to the op-amp and the op-amp's output swing capability?  There's no reason an op-amp can't work in this topology so it has to come down to the details and differences between the two compensation schemes.

Comment: @JohnD 
Both phase margins are 60 degrees. and the crossover frequency is 10Hz.